# Never reach the catch if I check Variable exists

Tags: powershell, error-handling

i know that I can check if a variable exists with

```
if ($null -eq "aaa"){set-variable -name "aaa"}
```

Can someone eplain why I never get into any catch block if I try this

```
try
{
   Get-Variable -Name 'aaa'
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]
{
   Set-Variable -Name 'aaa'
}
catch
{
   Set-Variable -Name 'aaa'
}
```

Comment: Use `Get-Variable -Name aaa -ErrorAction Stop` or set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`

Comment: In short: `try` / `catch` only acts on _terminating_ errors, whereas `Get-Variable` with the name of a nonexistent variable name emits a _non-terminating_ error by default, hence @MathiasR.Jessen's suggestion to promote it to a terminating one as shown. See the linked post for more information.